# Google sheets Arrayformula and Min question

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I am writing this formula but it's not working, could someone help me please

=Arrayformula(min(FILTER('Sheet1'!F:F,'Sheet1'!H:H = "No",'Sheet1'!D:D=A2:A)))

Comment: Hi! Can you please clarify what you want it to do?

Comment: Keep in mind that we can't see your data or layout. We don't know your end goal or desired result. Your formula that three ranges run full-column (e.g., F:F) while the last one runs A2:A. These are incongruous ranges. But three of the ranges in the formula are also in one sheet, while the fourth is in a different sheet; and the chances that those ranges on separate sheets are (or will remain) the same length is slim. The most efficient and effective way to receive help is to share a link to your spreadsheet (or a copy of it), with the permission set to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: Thanks for your replies, unfortunately sharing is closed outside our organization but I will try to create a similar sheet to be able to share.

The single formula =min(FILTER(Sheet1!F:F,Sheet1!H:H = "No",Sheet1!D:D=A3)) works just fine but when I try to convert it to an arrayformula I get the error "FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 6346. column count: 1. Actual row count: 6848, column count: 1."

Comment: Hello,

I created an example sheet.

The formula that works is

=min(FILTER(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!E:E = "No",Sheet1!A:A=A3))

Which retrieves the min price to a certain Item code from Sheet1 and it's working just fine but when I try to change it to an arrayformula like that

=ARRAYFORMULA(min(FILTER(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!E:E = "No",Sheet1!A:A=A3:A)))

I get a "No matches are found in FILTER evaluation. error

Here is a link to my sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_zKb9qseN5xde2q7u8plPtJKoN9WXuEd-72BopdZx5g/edit?usp=sharing

The formulas are in Sheet2 D2 and E2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a new sheet ("Erik Help") to your sample spreadsheet. The following formula in D2 is highlighted in green:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A,SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!A:C,Sheet1!E:E = "No"),3,1),3,FALSE))))`

You'll notice there is no `MIN` here.

Instead, I created a `FILTER` of `Sheet1!A:C` (not just `C:C`), `SORT`ed this so that prices run from smallest to greatest (i.e., minimum prices at the top), then performed a `VLOOKUP` for each ID. Since `VLOOKUP` only returns the first match it finds, it will always return the minimum (if the ID is found in the `FILTER`ed set; otherwise, null is returned by `IFERROR`).

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for the `arrayformula/min/filter` answer, you might want to try `query` for the mean time:

I have also made some assumptions on other columns as well. Neglect both `B and C` if you don't have a need of them right now.

#### Formula:

Column B:
`=arrayformula(ifNA(vlookup(A2:A&D2:D, {Sheet1!A2:A&Sheet1!C2:C,Sheet1!F2:F}, 2,0),"") )`

Column C:
`=arrayformula(if(isblank(D2:D), "", vlookup(A2:A&B2:B&D2:D, {Sheet1!A2:A&Sheet1!F2:F&Sheet1!C2:C,Sheet1!D2:D&" - "&Sheet1!E2:E}, 2, 0)))`

Column D:
`=query(query(Sheet1!A2:E, "select min(C) where E = 'No' group by A"), "offset 1", 0)`

- Given that the headers in Sheet1 are the following:

[image: sample1]

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- `D` is dependent on `A`
- `B` is dependent on `A and D`
- `C` is dependent on `A, B, and D`

Comment: Hello, thank you very much Erik, your formula worked perfectly I adjusted it to my needs and it is working

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @EgyGuy. If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer